# How to read data from a binary file in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

Hi I am trying to create an application which would read a binary file and then depending on the data within the binary file I will have to build a sequence of steps.

I have tried using FlatFileItemReader but I understand that in order to read a Binary File you would have to use SimpleBinaryBufferedReaderFactory.

Can some one please help me on how to read the binary data.

Comment: Do you have the format of the binary file? You read it like any other file, you read the file bytes at a time.

Comment: I am specifically looking at reading the  Binary File in Spring Batch application. I am currently able to read the binary file by converting to Bytes. When you try to read it like any other file in Spring batch you would need to know the structure of the data.  In this particular case I have multiple scenarios that happen and I need to use regex to read part of the file to collect  the data and then process it further. So the question is how will I be able to read the binary file from Spring Batch using SimpleBinaryBufferedReaderFactory.

Comment: `So the question is how will I be able to read the binary file from Spring Batch using SimpleBinaryBufferedReaderFactory.`: The first question should be what is an item in your binary file? How do you define an item? The `SimpleBinaryBufferedReaderFactory#setLineEnding` is what allows you to define that. The tests in this class may help you understand how it works: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/SimpleBinaryBufferedReaderFactoryTests.java#L29